# Partition index to reduce buffer busy waits?

Tags: oracle, optimization, database-partitioning

From time to time our Oracle response times decrease significally for a minute or two, without having extra load.
we were able to identify an insert statement, which produces a lot of **buffer busy waits**.

From the ADDM report, we got the following hint:

```
Consider partitioning the INDEX "IDX1" with object
ID 4711 in a manner that will evenly distribute concurrent DML across
multiple partitions.
```

To be honest: I am not sure what that means. I don't know what a partitioned index is. I only can Image that it means to create a Partition with a local index.

Can you help me out here?
There is a very high frequency of reading and writing to that table. no updates or deletes are used.

Thanks,
E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > I am not sure what that means.

Oracle is telling you that there is a lot of concurrent ("at the same time") activity on a very small part of your index.  This happens a lot.

Consider an index column `TAB1_PK` on table `TAB1` whose values are inserted from a sequence `TAB1_S`.  Suppose you have 5 database sessions all inserting into `TAB1` at the same time.

Because `TAB1_PK` is indexed, and because the sequence is generating values in numeric order, what happens is that all those sessions have to read and update the same blocks of the index at the same time.

This can cause a lot of contention -- *way* more than you would expect, due to the way indexes work with multi-version read consistency.  I mean, in some rare situations (depending on how the transaction logic is written and the number of concurrent sessions), it can really be crippling.

The (really) old way to avoid this problem was to use a reverse key index.  That way, the sequential column values did not all go to the same index blocks.

However, that is a two-edged sword.  On the one hand, you get less contention because you're inserting all over the index (good).  On the other hand, your rows are going all over the index, meaning you cannot cache them all.  You've just turned a big logical I/O problem into a physical I/O problem!

Nowadays, we have a better solution -- a GLOBAL HASH PARTITION on the index.

With a GHP, you can specify the number of hash buckets and use that to trade-off between how much contention you need to handle vs how compact you want the index updates (for better buffer caching).  The more index hash partitions you use, the better your concurrency but the worse your index block buffer caching will be.

I find a number (of global hash partitions) around 16 is pretty good.

Comment: Hi Matthew, thanks a lot!! Your description is waaaay better than the official Oracle Version :)  i have just one more question: why does this issue occur on random (at least it seems so) and not even when we peak with the traffic ?

Comment: If it is really the same problem, it would depend on the number of sessions concurrently inserting, updating, and reading new or recent records using that index.  The updates/selects hurt because Oracle spends a lot of time applying UNDO to reconstruct read-consistent views of those right-most index blocks.  I spoke about this briefly in section 3 of an OAUG Paper a few years back.  Here is a link: https://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/key/FUfJhL7PYsWvmd.  I've only seen this problem reach a noticeable level one time -- but that one time was very serious and system-wide in impact.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure if it is the same problem, but the DBA suspects it. So I will create that index and than we have to monitor :) thanks, E.